# How can i make <a href='$game_link' target='_blank'>$game_link</a> a button

Tags: php, html, variables, hyperlink

Hello I'm to trying to make this variable $game_link which is the url from the database a button, but seem not to get it right? I need help on it please. This is the code $game_link.

Comment: what have u tried ?

Comment: "This is the code $game_link."
I don't think that thats its the code.. or at least not everything of it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create an HTML button that acts like a link?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Try This . I hope It will Work For You . If you are try to write this in PHP . 
And This is Your Styling . I mean Your Css .

```
    <style type="text/css">
    .submit_button {
text-decoration: none; font: menu;
display: inline-block; padding: 2px 8px;
background: ButtonFace; color: ButtonText;
border-style: solid; border-width: 2px;
border-color: ButtonHighlight ButtonShadow ButtonShadow ButtonHighlight;
 }
  .submit_button:active {
   border-color: ButtonShadow ButtonHighlight ButtonHighlight ButtonShadow;
   }
</style>
```

Here Is Your Anchor Tag Code

```
   <a href="<?php echo $game_link ?>" class="submit_button" target="_BLANK"><?php echo $game_link ?></a>
```

Let Me Know If your problem get solved . Thanks

Comment: I mean i want it to be a button? how do i do that

Comment: Add Some CSS or I will send you the code ?

Comment: Send the code please

Comment: Coder don't do it. :)
Boy, try it by yourself and post the code you've tried with. We're here to help you and find problems with YOUR code, but not to write code for you.

Comment: I am Sorry Twinfriends i already post this ans .

Comment: no problem, you don't have to apologize. I mean, if you want to do that for him, its okay. Its just that he won't learn anything this way... He will copy paste it and everything is fine. 20 minutes later he will post his next question because he's in trouble again and it ends up that you've written his whole application.

Comment: Coder thanks a lot bro and the other guy mind yourself here oh